# How to reset Transformer output properties?

Tags: java, xml

Here is a small snippet trying to reset output properties of a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Properties originalOutputProperties = transformer.getOutputProperties();

System.out.println("ORIG= " + originalOutputProperties);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

System.out.println("BEFORE RESET= " + transformer.getOutputProperties());
transformer.setOutputProperties(originalOutputProperties);

System.out.println("AFTER RESET= " + transformer.getOutputProperties());
```

And this is the ouput:

```
ORIG= {}
BEFORE RESET= {encoding=UTF-8}
AFTER RESET= {encoding=UTF-8}
```

As you can see, the original output properties are not the original ones.

How to reset the output properties?

**EDIT**
The transformer is reused multiple times.
In this case, here is what I expect:

```
ORIG= {}
BEFORE RESET= {encoding=UTF-8}
AFTER RESET= {}

ORIG= {}
BEFORE RESET= {indent=yes, encoding=UTF-8, {http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount=4, omit-xml-declaration=yes}
AFTER RESET= {}
```

Comment: I can't account for the behaviour, but I would generally recommend creating a new Transformer for each transformation. It's important to reuse the Templates object if you use the same stylesheet repeatedly, but creating a new Transformer from the Templates object should be at least as cheap as resetting the existing one.

Comment: @MichaelKay I chose to create new Transformer each time. I can tolerate any "overhead" introduced by the repeated creations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project I have to maintain relies on Java 1.6.0_24. When calling `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()`, this version of Java returns an instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl`.

This implementation allows the reset of the output properties **once**.

My workaround is to create a new fresh `Transformer` instance from the `TransfomerFactory` each time a transformer is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try `transformer.setOutputProperties(null);` before setting back `originalOutputProperties` (if still applicable). According to the `Transformer.setOutputProperties(Properties)` Javadoc:

> If argument to this function is null, any properties previously set
>   are removed, and the value will revert to the value defined in the
>   templates object.

------------ UPDATE ------------

From `TransformerImpl` I see that the `reset()` method resets everything, not only the output parameters. Maybe this is too much for your needs...

Another alternative may consist in individually resetting the properties you want (e.g., `OutputKeys.ENCODING`). This should work more than once.

Yet another alternative may consist in using one `Transformer` per set of output parameters you have to use. But whether you should proceed this way depends on how many such sets of parameters you happen to use...

Comment: It works **only** when `transformer.setOutputProperties(null);` is called **the very first time**. On successive calls on the same transformer instance, the `setOutputProperties(null)` call becomes inoperant. (**Java 1.6.0_24**)

Comment: `reset()` calls internally `setOutproperties(null)` thus I'll face the same issue. Individually resetting the properties doesn't work either.